# getting the innerhtml of input in td

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the values of inputs in the column of a table.

```
<table>
  <tr class="mytr">
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout">123</input></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout">ad</input></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout">as</input></td>
    <td class="mytd"><textarea rows="1" class="bout">122222</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="mytr">
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout">45</input></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout">3</input></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout">4</input></td>
    <td class="mytd"><textarea rows="1" class="bout">5</textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can get the tables row like this

```
$('.mytr').each(function(index) {
});
```

and it iterates over the rows perfectly fine but how do I now get the value of td. I tried

```
$('.mytr').each(function(index) {
  alert($('.bout:eq(0)').html()) ;
});
```

to get the innerhtml of the input of the first tds but I get empty value. I was expecting `123`. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `input` elements cannot have children. Were you looking for the `value` attribute?

Comment: @Autolycus You have > 1000 rep and yet you need someone to format your question correctly for you. That's a little sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inputs we use `.val()`:

```
$('.mytr').each(function() {

    alert($(this).find('.bout').eq(0).val());

});
```

Docs for `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val

If you want to get the value of all of the inputs in a row:

```
$('.mytr').each(function() {

    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        alert($(this).find('.bout').val());
    });

});
```

**UPDATE**

I just noticed `<input type="text" class="bout">123</input>`, a valid input element would look like this:

```
<input type="text" class="bout" value="123" />
```

Here is some awesome documentation on HTML input tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: The value the OP is looking for is not actually a value of the `input`, so `val` won't return it. I think the OP was actually intending to use `value` attributes rather than child text nodes though, so your answer should be correct once the OP has made their code valid!

Comment: He'd need to use input element properly first.

Comment: @Autolycus `OP` stands for `Origional Poster`.

Comment: @Autolycus Also note that if you want to get the value of a `textarea` element you use `.val()` and not `.html()`, even though `textarea`s have opening and closing tags.

Comment: one issue, when I use $('.mytr').each(function() {

    alert($(this).find('.bout').eq(0).val());

});   it works for the first row and on the second row it gives undefined. I think its loosing index

Comment: Here is a demo using the exact code from my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/haSGJ/. Check to make sure your HTML is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
<input type="text" class="bout">123</input>
```

Is invalid HTML.
Input fields are self-closing tags and should be formatted like this:

```
<input type="text" class="bout" value="123" />
```

One you have that, then you can use the jquery .val function to get the value of the input field.
Using this just as an example:

```
$('tr.mytr td:first input:first').val();
```

Will get the value of the first input field. Hopefully you can use that example to figure out what you need to do from there.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to define input element and its value:

```
<input type="text" class="bout" value="123" />
```

And get the value inside your loop:

```
var value = $(this).find('.bout:first').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
<input type="text" class="bout">123</input>
```

it should be like

```
<input type="text" value="123" class="bout"></input>
```

and js

try this

```
  $(function(){

    $('.mytr').each(function(index) {
      var current_tr = $(this);
      alert($('.bout:eq(0)', current_tr).val());

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Input elements doesn't have childs.

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="3" />
```

note the /> self closing tag.

to get the value of all inputs:

```
$('input').val()
```

to summarize:

```
<table>
  <tr class="mytr">
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout" value="123" /></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout" value="ad" /></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout" value="as" /></td>
    <td class="mytd"><textarea rows="1" class="bout">122222</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="mytr">
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout" value="45" /></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout" value="3" /></td>
    <td class="mytd"><input type="text" class="bout" value="4" /></td>
    <td class="mytd"><textarea rows="1" class="bout" value="5</textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jquery: 
you can get all in a variable like :

```
var values = $('tr input').val();
```

or

```
$('tr input').each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you said you expect `123` here is a way

```
alert($('.mytr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bVhzj/34/